# Insert data in CSV file into SQL Server table in chunks?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I need to read load a CSV file into a SQL Server table. Below code inserts one row at a time and it takes a very long time. Is there a way to insert the data into the table in bulk chunks or any other way faster?

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(r'd:/data_file.csv')
for index row in df.iterrows():
   cursor.execute("insert into <table name>"
   "(Name, phone, address)"
   "VALUES(?, ?, ?)",
    (Row['FirstandLastName'], row['xxx'], row['11 adison ln']))
```

Update:

I have tried this:

```
query=f"""insert into <table name>"
   "(Name, phone, address)"
   "VALUES(?, ?, ?)"""
values_list=[tuple(row) for_, row in df.iterrows()]

   try:
     cursor.executemany(query, values_list)
   except Exception as e:
     print(e)
```

I get syntax error on this line:

```
cursor.executemany(query, values_list)

SQL Server Statement(s) could not be prepared(8180)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert all rows from the pandas DataFrame into the database table at once, you can use the `executemany()` method instead of executing individual insert statements for each row. This method allows you to execute the same SQL insert statement multiple times with different sets of parameters (values) in a single call, making it more efficient for bulk insertion.

Here's how you can do it:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3  # Assuming you are using SQLite as the database
df = pd.read_csv(r'd:/data_file.csv')
conn = sqlite3.connect('your_database_name.db')
cursur = conn.cursor()
table_name = 'your_table_name'
query = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ?...)"
values_list = [tuple(row) for _, row in df.iterrows()]
cursur.executemany(query, values_list)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

This approach is more efficient when dealing with a large number of rows, as it reduces the number of individual database operations required for each row insertion.

Comment: I get this error on line cursur.executemany(query, values_list) incorrect syntax, sql could not be prepared

Comment: Please provide the complete query.

Comment: when I do print(values_list), I see the list. But cursur.executemany(query, values_list) nor cursur.execute(query, values_list) does not work. I get syntax error on that line. query is "insert into <table name> (Name, phone, address) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"

Comment: You need to check your data there must be some missing values in that.

Comment: @Muhamad Usman Ali Bukhari, I think I know what is the problem. cursur.executemany(query, values_list), in values_list there 100 of list items, not just one list. values_list is basically list version of the whole data frame. I need to insert this list to the ms sql table.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the answer of your problem.

Comment: so, I dont know how to resolve this problem. Inserting one row at a time is taking a very long time.

Comment: try this:
table_name = 'your_table_name'
df.to_sql(table_name, conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)

Comment: this is for sqlite, I am working with mssql

Answer (score 0):

Use the `BULK INSERT` query to load the CSV or import it directly on SQL Server Management Studio.  Follow the link below for example on how to do that:

https://blog.skyvia.com/3-easy-ways-to-import-csv-file-to-sql-server/

Comment: bulk insert will not work, I can only insert data remotely. Dont have access to mssql server locally, only remote with python

Answer (score -2):

It would be much faster if you called the `cursor.execute` once rather than for each row

Comment: I updated the post. I am not familiar with how to perfrom insert into a df

Comment: The df declaration should be after the import:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).